# What comes in the box?

Tags: purchasing

I've noticed that the RPi comes caseless. But does it just come with the computer itself? Or are there cables, instructions, swag (stickers, balloons, etc) that ship with it?

Comment: Shame this is off-topic, I really like Joe's answer

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the US from RS I received a brown box with the Raspberry Pi in an anti-static bag sandwiched between two pieces of foam. Also included was a quick start guide and a regulatory notice. Element 14 shipped in a smaller white box, also in an anti-static bag. There are no cables or SD cards included.

[image]

Comment: It took all my strength to not downvote you simply for having two of them :)

Answer (score 9):

Just the Pi - no stickers, t-shirts, etc.

It's designed to keep costs down, so it'd be somewhat silly if this was mitigated at the last moment by shoving unnecessary cables and other stuff in there that adds to shipping / package costs.

I for one am quite glad of this, I have enough power supplies / cables / SD cards lying around that I don't need any more unnecessary ones. I'd prefer to save on the cost (and in reality I wish more products took this bare-bones approach!)

If you do need other things, I believe some places are starting to offer "packs" of USB cables and SD cards, otherwise you just need to buy them separately - the "essentials" aren't at all expensive.

Answer (score 8):

I ordered from Farnell and received just the board in a ESD bag, EM compliance notice and an order receipt. The shipping label also stated that there would be a "T-shirt" inside but, well, there was none :(

Lack of adapter can be inconvenient, but in the meantime you can power RPi from a high-power/charging USB port, if you have it on your computer or a powered USB hub.

You should **NOT** attach it to the standard USB port however, because it will not supply enough power.

Comment: So the power adapter isn't even included?

Comment: No. It isn't, but until you get one you can often use your phone's charger.

Comment: A standard USB port is fine for powering the Pi. I have two on my desk running off PC USB ports without issue. If additional hardware devices are attached to USB ports the power will likely be insufficient, but for a keyboard/mouse it's fine.